# How do I refresh paperclip thumbnails with an offset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, spree

I want to refresh/recreate thumbnails with 'paperclip' that have ids above 1000, is there a way to do this?

I've tried everything but forking the gem and adding an offset to the finder.

Comment: what do you want....? ids above 1000 ?

Comment: I have a really huge amount of images in the database, and I need to refresh the thumbnails of all of them. The task ran just fine until it failed at an attachment with the parent id of 1000. I now want to continue where I left off instead of having to run the task again and risk running into the same problem.

Comment: @eoy which rake task you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reprocess! to regenerate a specific set of Paperclip images.  Something like:

```
Model.where('parent_id > 1000').each do |model|
  model.paperclip_attachment.reprocess!
end
```

There's more information available in the paperclip documentation:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation